# c++ delete object outside of creation scope with pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, memory-address

I'm doing some learning exercises in c++ and I ran into an interesting question. Take this sample program.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

char* pointer1;

void temp() {

    char* s1 = new char;
    *s1 = 'z';
    pointer1 = s1;
    std::cout << *pointer1 << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++) {
        // Waste some processor time.
    }
}

int main() {

    temp();
    std::cout << *pointer1 << std::endl;
    delete pointer1;
    //delete &pointer1;
    std::cout << *pointer1 << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

When you run it it prints out 'z' twice then some random garbage. Which is what I expected. If you un-comment 'delete &pointer1' and comment out the first delete and run the program you get an invalid pointer error from the output. I'm assuming this is deleting the address and what's actually stored there is remaining.

My question is when calling 'delete pointer1' does it delete 'char* s1' or just the address to where ever the s1 is stored? When calling 'delete &pointer1' is the address being deleted but s1 still in memory?

Comment: You are asking the wrong questions entirely. None of this matters to beginners *at all*, and to anyone else mostly when dealing with poorly written (legacy) code. Focus on learning the language from a good and up-to-date book and stop wasting your precious time with trial and error. The results tend to be meaningless anyway.

Comment: `*pointer1` after `delete pointer1;` is UB, `delete &pointer1;` is also UB.

Comment: Using value of deleted pointer is an Undefined Behavior so there is not such thing as expected result here.

Comment: I echo @BaummitAugen 's comment. Learners of the language today should almost never use `new` and `delete`; use standard containers and shared/unique pointers and `make_shared`/`make_unique`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen This is why I don't use stack overflow much. Someone says I want to learn A. Then people come out and say "no you don't want to learn A learn B instead or just forget A altogether". This place has too many people deterring others from learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address that `pointer1` points to has been allocated by `new`. Hence, it is correct, even necessary, to call `delete` on that address.

However, `&pointer1` gives you the address where `pointer1` itself is stored. And this memory block has not been allocated by `new`. Hence, it is strictly illegal to call `delete` on it, which is precisely what the error is telling you.

So, yes, `delete pointer1` frees the memory that has been allocated by `new` previously. But no, `delete &pointer1` doesn't do anything but being illegal.

Additionally, accessing memory you called `delete` on previously is undefined behavior. So, your second `*pointer1` is also nothing you want to write in a program that you do not want to crash or, even worse, that gives you unpredictable results.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Marked you as answer.